# ssh error bash: 22: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, command-not-found

I am pretty new to unix, so please bare with me...

when i try to connect to my server running ubuntu server through terminal on my ubuntu workstation I get this error:

- `bash: 22: command not found`

the command I type in to connect is :

- `ssh user@ip 22`
  then i get the response that asks for the user's pass, after i enter it i get promted with that error.

I have tried resinstalling openssh-client by:

- `sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-client`
- `sudo apt-get install openssh-client`

also tried updating my repos:
 - `sudo apt-get update`

sadly no result...

Comment: Please [read](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu). You are doing it wrong; your command should be `ssh USER@IP -p PORT`, *22* is the default port for SSH, so you need not specify it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Port 22 is the standard port used to connect to `sshd`.  It is used by default, so unless you have configured your remote host to listen on a non-standard port in your `sshd_config`, then all you need to do is `ssh user@ip`.

If your remote host were listening on port 2222, for instance, the syntax for specifying that would be `ssh -p 2222 user@ip`.  It looks like you are trying to do `ssh -p 22 user@ip`, but like I said, that is unnecessary because 22 is the default port that SSH tries to connect to.

What your command is actually doing is trying to execute the non-existent command `22` on the remote host.  Everything after the `ssh` command is interpreted as a command to be executed on the remote host (and for best practices, should normally be enclosed in quotes).  For instance, `ssh user@ip hostname` would return the remote hostname, because it is executing that command on the remote machine and then exiting SSH back to your local shell.